# Help vet the rules for a possible future contest

Tags: discussion, advertising

## tl;dr:

One of the ways we keep the lights on around here is by letting companies tell our visitors how awesome their products are in exchange for money. (I think the technical term for this is 'advertising'.) Occasionally, a company is interested in showing their support more specifically for the kind of devs who are active participants on the site. Usually by giving them stuff. I think the technical term for this is <strike>bribery</strike> *contests*. We’ve [done this before](http://apptivate.ms) and we have the opportunity to do it again with a different partner company. We’re looking for your feedback to help us do it right.

## The details:

The potential client (we’ll call them Mindtopiary) wants to run an event similar to [the Apptivate reviewer contest](http://apptivate.ms/contest/#reviewer-contest) where devs can opt into the contest, try out the product (that part is optional), and get chances to win cool prizes for creating quality content in tags associated with their products. (The prizes are actually cool, too. Potentially rhyming with… er… “blockulus swift”.) Mindtopiary’s main goal is to help software developers remember their product and company positively. (We think it’s **awesome** that they feel that Stack Overflow is the best partner to help them achieve that goal.)

That means that they are fully committed to working with us on how to run an event that generates only positive contributions on the site. The goal is to run something this community will like and remember, not just to bump activity for a couple weeks before fading away. Thus: if you don’t like this, **neither does Mindtopiary**.

We’re looking for your suggested tweaks on the current rough outline:

1. Interested users sign up to participate in the event via a separate mini-site.
2. They try out the product via a free sandbox (optional - users can participate without doing this).
3. They ask and answer questions on the Mindtopiary tag, or on the FeeFriend tag. (FeeFriend is Mindtopiary’s parent company.)
4. Each non-closed non-deleted post on [mindtopiary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mindtopiary) gets 5 entries into the prize raffle. Additionally, each non-closed non-deleted post on [feefriend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feefriend) gets 1 entry into the prize raffle.
5. SE staff monitors the tags during the period to help ensure there’s no crap content getting through or other abuse occurring. (We don’t think these rules will incentivize the posting of crap, but we’re committed to ensuring that if we’ve missed something, the burden doesn’t fall on moderators and high-rep users.)

We could use some help making tweaks and edits here. For example: **do you think there should there be a vote threshold other than non-closed/non-deleted?** Our concern is that too high a threshold for entry reduces the potential applicant pool, making raffle chances artificially scarce and incentivizing voting rings and sockpuppetry.

Anything that turns this event into an annoyance or a burden makes this event a total non-starter for us, so please help us make sure we’re doing it right.

---

## Update:

It seems like most folks would be pretty okay with this, **provided that we added or specify the following constraints**:

- Non-closed, non-deleted posts with score >= 1 are eligible for raffle entries
- **Duplicates are not eligible**, however the older question in the duplicate pair is eligible if it was posted during the contest period
- Prize value will be capped at $`x`, where `x` is an amount of money that makes things cool but not anything to go crazy over, and prizes will not be cash or cash-equivalent
- The raffle drawing will take place at least 7 days after the close of the posting period to allow for content moderation to shake itself out
- SE staff will monitor the contest tags and nuke bad content and disqualify bad acting users on sight

We'll keep the community updated if this goes forward.

## Update (again):

Based on your feedback, [the contest is now live](http://braintree.stackexchange.com). Good hunting!

Comment: Meh, I think a vote threshold would encourage socketry and voteringing.  I can say this authoritatively because I am currently constructing a vast army of sockpuppets to upvote my questions and answers.

Comment: *Potentially rhyming with… er… “blockulus swift”.* I've always wanted a Octopus Lift.

Comment: I'm skeptical about the coolness of the prizes as "bacon" does not rhyme with "blockulus swift" (which incidentally, is also the name of Taylor's lesser known sibling).

Comment: Chocula's Miffed? Mock you Lundqvist? I give up! What could it be?

Comment: what is the prize !!!!

Comment: @Coffee Nothing's official yet. Prizes will be announced when the event is finalized.

Comment: Do we have the capacity to handle the extra work?

Comment: Are statistics available about that previous contest? That would help make more informed decisions. Raw figures like #Q&A, after effects, but also e.g. data comparing unwanted behaviour (duplicates, non-constructive comments, 'not an answer') of the set of contest questions versus all SO questions.

Comment: Is this a secret santa ploy? Stalkyou Withgift?

Comment: http://www.oculus.com/rift/

Comment: I think you should add "not negative vote" and also only include the 5 most up-voted answer to any question with more then 5 answers.

Comment: No Octopus Lift as a prize? AN OUTRAGE.

Comment: "Based on your feedback" - I was fairly certain the feedback was "don't do this!" Nice prizes, but... not participating as it *ruins the fun of Stack Overflow (the intrinsic motivation)*. This contest would almost be better if the extrinsic rewards were unknown, and it was simply a "please participate" advertisement, and rewards were announced to congratulate the top users at the end. That keeps the extrinsic motivation away.

Answer (score 40):

Update:

I've been reading through some of the suggestions raised in this thread and elsewhere, and I've compiled some thoughts that should help assure these contest do not run into the problems I raised below.

### Support From the Community First

When looking at these contests, support for the subject or tag *has* to come from the community first. We don't want a situation where we're fabricating interest in a non-existent tag simply because an advertiser is "paying" us to do so. But if a subject or project is *already* an integral part of this site, it's quite a boon to us when internal developer teams take an interest in providing deeper, authoritative support in those tags. So when its already a good fit, contests can be a good way for these project teams to give back to the community for the hard work you put into supporting those subjects.

### No Cash or Cash-Equivalent Prizes

Cash or cash-equivalent prizes should be avoided. There's something about a gift card or stuffing a bit of cash in my pocket that takes away too much from the *spirit* of these contests. Contests are supposed to be fun and a chance show off a bit on occasion. The "trophy" at the end of the activity should reflect that goal. Appropriate prizes are more about "bragging rights" to the people interested in the subject. Cash is just indiscriminate payment, and it is simply more apt to attract the wrong players and behaviors we are trying to avoid.

### The Activity Should Fit the Site

The activities surrounding the contest should NOT try to *bend* the site in ways that are conspicuously out of place on the site. We are about content, first and foremost. Contests should help move the site forward and (ideally) leave it in better shape than they found it. If the contest is going to create artifacts that aren't going to make sense after it's gone, make sure they're cleaned up. And make sure the contest doesn't make too much a nuisance of itself to the "regular" users of the site (it's either low-key enough to be ignored or maybe allow them to opt out, if possible).

### The Content *Has* to Come First

This might go without saying, but the goals of a contest should NOT encourage crap (even unintentionally). That's a pretty tall order, but if the goal is quality over quantity, you're half way there. Make sure the winners are selected by the preponderance of the community; the need for greater numbers avoids cheating. I love the idea of "eligible posts" earning an entry into a raffle. This avoids a lot of the vote-fraud problems where friends might conspire to pump up scores. Keep using the *normal* community-moderation tools to vet the content. Posts with a score of zero or less would not count. A closed post would be disqualified. Duplicates allow "first entries" to prevail — but make sure Moderators show increased restraint (but more diligence) when administering the content of a contest. And at the end of it all, make sure you allow  enough time for the community process to "happen." Final tallies should be delayed long enough for the voting, closing, and related meta activities to shake out.

### Keep Building on What Works

It's encouraging that this contest is modeled after an event that ran quite successful the last time. If we can continually improve on what works and avoid the problems of the past, this could be a nice diversion while keeping it a productive experience. But it's going to take a combination of fun-over-profit and stepping back a bit on occasion to avoid always taking ourselves too seriously to make this work. Enjoy what we've built here together. If a contest goes well, let's celebrate. If it goes poorly, let's regroup. But most of all, keep it light, have fun, and keep talking in threads like this.

[End Update]

---

We've talked a lot internally about the problems of providing "valuable prizes" as being a poor way to motivate posts for these contests. Stack Overflow is driven by *intrinsic* motivations (the self-directed reason folks contribute their heard-earned expertise to this site). These prizes are often seen as a harmless way to show our appreciation for the content… but unfortunately, **the "cooler" the prize is,** the more you replace that intrinsic motivation with the drive just to get that *stuff.* I'm wondering if that problem isn't exacerbated when the contest itself driven by the marketing efforts of a third party.

I'm not suggesting any questionable motives in the contest itself — if an advertiser wants to include some type of *off-site* contest in their promotions (subject to our advertising standards), more power to them — but I don't think you can easily legislate away poor motivations when the "prize" is still a *carrot on a stick.* It's nice to think that we're simply providing a bit of extra fun for what folks are *already* doing on our sites,  but I think Stack Overflow may simply be too big to say, "give our users some stuff, and we'll be sure it won't turn into the wrong motivations in this instance."

We also have to consider that we have always worked hard to keep a healthy distance between our advertisers and our actual Q&A content. That may not be a problem here if their content is presumably *already* an intrinsic part of our site. But I think we have to be *especially* careful if the "valuable prizes" are part of the promotion itself… especially if you believe as I do that they will lead to poorer results.

[**The Surprising Truth About What Motivates Us**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6XAPnuFjJc)

[image: RSA Animate]

Comment: Following @JonathanDrapeau That video is cool and really gives some point to learn.

Comment: @bjb568 +1 for the plus one, -1  for dissing my favorite RSA video <grin>.

Comment: Good concerns: 1.Things that feel like paying in a collaborative/generosity based environment can mess with intrinsic motivations and can be dangerous. 2. Messing with any incentives for typing runs the risk of generating noise. I don't think #1 is a real issue here - occasional contests with highly randomized outcomes (so it doesn't feel much like you're getting paid for your time) seem fairly benign. #2 is what this post (and the current plan, including staff review) is designed to consider.  Plus, to my knowledge, we had no real issues with the MS one last year.

Comment: Less clear concerns: It's not clear to me what behavior is being allowed that wouldn't be normally (other than promoting your product, which is normal when you're advertising). And the "hypothetical contests" line leads off with a sense that you think they're trying to pull a fast one somehow. I thought this was an unusually direct acknowledgment to the community of why the company is looking to do this, and they were totally supportive of going to the community for input and other constraints to ensure no harm is done.

Comment: I'm both massively- shocked and heartened to have you write this; thank you. I agree, given people's nature (and I don't exclude myself) this sort of thing is incredibly difficult to manage well, which implies that the answer is "do it off-site or not at all". However, other sites manage to have answering binges in certain tags and SO _ought_ be able to manage the same, though I suspect additional disincentives would be required.

Answer (score 24):

The problem with this sort of approach is that, as already obliquely referenced, you are rewarding people for churning out crap.

Everyone who wants to win will be churning out as many questions/answers (I assume post includes both?) as they can without any regard to whether someone else might already have done so.

Expect to see a lot of 1 line answers and questions if the contest becomes a thing people really try and win, often the same answer posted multiple times, etc.

A better system might be to at the end of the contest period take the top X highest voted posts as the finalists and then have judges either from the sponsors, from SE or as a community vote select the winner/runner up/etc from those.

(The fact that number of votes only selects a finalist not end position will help reduce the impact of voting rings a lot. Of course if any of these questions make it into HNQ then all bets are off as it will see a massive surge...)

Comment: Adding to this; if what you describe is actually what happens, we'd have to be very diligent about marking duplicates. The SE team would have to work hard to do this quickly since there wouldn't be any gold badge holders in the tag, and the longer duplicate questions remain open the more answers they'll pull in and so more merges may have to be done, creating more work. There'd also need to be some good rules about dupes (e.g. always dupe of earlier question) or something to eliminate any cries of foul play from inconsistent handling. Could the SE team do that as part of point 5?

Comment: Good point. We could certainly monitor and mark as duplicates, and make it very clear in the contest rules how we'd do so. The older post in the duplicate set would get the raffle entr(y/ies).

Comment: @abbyhairboat What if, in a rush to check out the trial, multiple people have the same question around the same time and post unintentional duplicates? Who "wins"? Do you think this would be too unlikely to care about (or maybe just handle it case-by-case)? Is it sufficient to just say "earliest gets kept, rules are rules" (this is the action I support, personally)? Just playing devil's advocate.

Comment: That's why it's a good thing this would be monitored by humans. If I can see that they were posted a few seconds apart, I'd consider it a good-faith effort and probably close one as a duplicate but let both keep their raffle entries (assuming that's technically possible).

Comment: @abbyhairboat SE is staffed by humans?!

Comment: I commonly see questions on stack overflow where I post an answer and there are 3 or 4 similar answers all posted already or in the next minute or so. That's not copying, that's just the time needed to write. But how do you tell the difference between someone who is 30seconds slower posting compared to someone who just opens the page, cut and pastes an answer, and quickly tweaks a few words then posts?

Answer (score 20):

I think this is a good plan as long as outline point 5 (SE monitoring for crap) is taken seriously and done effectively. This will be critical.<sup>†</sup>

I think the vote threshold should simply be either >0 or >=0 (undecided). That is, the requirements are non-closed, non-deleted, and non-poorly-received. Anything higher than 0 I feel will incentivize voting rings like you say (or if not full on voting rings, even just small things like going into chat and saying "vote for my post").

---

<sup>†</sup> I think the rules for handling duplicate questions should be fleshed out ahead of time, though. [Tim B's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277154/616460) raises a good point in that I think we could expect to see people asking questions without care of what others may have asked. Duplicates would have to be handled quickly - the longer they stay open, the more answers they attract, and this leads to potentially more work merging questions. The problem is if two users legitimately have the same good question around the same time (which might be reasonable to expect for a new product near the start of a trial), closing one as a duplicate of the other could potentially lead to some bad blood. I do not have any good ideas how to handle this, other than handling it case-by-case outside of the system.

The handling of duplicate answers is also going to be tricky, as typically nothing is really done about duplicate answers. It would be fairly easy to squeeze out a few extra raffle entries by simply posting the same answer that somebody else just posted, worded slightly differently. Of course, if *everybody* does this, maybe the proportions of raffle entries in the end won't be changed much, but that's too much math for me.

SE staff would also have to pay special attention to cases where a user posts an answer and down-votes all other *correct* answers on that question.

Comment: I was about to post this on the main post and it relates - What incentive is there for people to actually upvote content in the contest? For example, if I'm contributing to [tag:mindtopiary] hoping for a raffle contest then it's completely to my advantage to _not_ upvote other users content since I will actively be hurting my chances. In addition the main users reading the tag likely will be from that tag too and have the same disincentive to vote (unless the company is planning on actively voting for good content? Maybe that would be useful).

Comment: @enderland That's a good point in that, since the trial is only open to people who are in the contest, you won't really have people *not* in the trial also voting - I mean you'll expect some non-contest users voting on just the *structure* of the question (e.g. is it a well-written question) but not so much on the content, which nobody not in the contest will know about. Hm...

Comment: @enderland On the other hand, if that *does* happen you'd expect to see a high amount of negatively scored questions in the end. If that pattern is noticed, then the rules could always be adjusted at the end to mitigate (e.g. if we notice an average offset of -2 on every question, set the threshold to -2 at the end). I think it's something that *could* be dealt with as long as it is monitored. Maybe special monitoring to identify people who downvote unusually large amounts of questions in that tag.

Comment: @Jason re: "since the trial is only open to people who are in the contest" -- that's not true. (Sorry if that was unclear in my question.) The trial is open to anyone in the entire world.

Comment: @abbyhairboat Ah; in that case, is there a possibility of this company, say, providing a link to SO from the trial page as the unofficial (or even official) source for product questions? That could be a good way to drive up activity all around, and also establish a more permanent, long-term connection and community, and *maybe* even give them a good support forum. (If so, you'd want to make sure [tag:mindtopiary] gets a good tag wiki entry, too.)

Comment: @Jason It's certainly worth looking into - that's a good idea.

Answer (score 15):

The biggest problem that exists here is that there is a real incentive to try and game any system put in place here.  Now people are going after a real prize instead of imaginary internet points.  I believe that the best way to discourage crap posts is to modify the penalties we already hand out for posting crap.

Most of the normal things we do would still work (question and answer bans, etc.).  It could also add a loss of prize raffle spot.  Dupe a question that has been around for a while?  Lose a raffle.  Write a post that is totally junk just to pick up raffles? Lose raffles.  Mis-tag something just to pick up raffles? Lose a few.  This should hopefully discourage the crap posts by making bad posts detrimental to winning anything.

This all hinges on the premise that the SE staff will be doing a lot (or all) of the mod duties for this.  They should be able to be trusted as impartial judges who will never "be out to get anyone" or "are just trying to increase their odds of winning".  If they are the ones who are dropping the dupe hammer and handing out the penalties (or removing undeserved penalties), all should be well.  Above all, whoever is doing this cannot have any real or perceived conflict of interest.

Comment: One issue I have with this approach is it also potentially discourages users from doing the *right* thing; or at least causes some conflict if a user genuinely *thinks* they're doing the right thing (rather than them trying to game the syste). Same with a user that posts a junk post without actual ill intentions (i.e. they genuinely and innocently provided an incorrect answer). I see a potential for a lot of drama on meta with these kinds of rules.

Comment: @JasonC Hopefully those people that want to do the right thing and just have a bad go at it will want to work harder at doing the right thing the right way.  If they see downvotes, etc. hopefully the penalty will motivate them to improve.  Even more so, I hope they will read the rules better before posting.  We already have to deal with people on SE that are trying to get help and post poor questions.  Sometimes they show up on meta and ask how they can do better.  Other times they show up on meta to complain of perceived elitism, unkindness, etc.  We are not going to get away from the drama,

Comment: @JasonC we are just going to have to deal with it as normal.  And point people back to the rules that say "Sorry, we expect you to do this and you failed.  When you fail, X happens.  Please try again."

Answer (score 11):

A couple more things for the company in question.

1. Do not rely on crowdsourcing alone. Have your engineers and tech people provide answers as well. Just mark those answers to let us know those are your employees answering those questions (so we know we're not competing with them in the contest).

> 1. Interested users sign up to participate in the event via a separate mini-site.
> 2. They try out the product via a free sandbox (optional - users can participate without doing this).

2. Allow us to play with the free sandbox even without needing to register/login to access it. I realize this may not be possible with every piece of functionality, but if just part of the sandbox was accessible without needing a login, that would go a long way, even if that sandbox got wiped and rebuilt on an hourly schedule. And I also realize that Tech Evangelists are heavily judged based on the number of sign ups they can generate, but as users, we do not have the same perspective as they do. As new users, we just want to know if something is worth our while, before we invest too much energy into it.
3. Documentation. Allow us to access your documentation without needing to login, or without needing to download a set of pdf documents. Please do tell us if your documentation is missing something, or if it is glossing over a feature which is not completely finished yet. Having developer documentation not hidden beyond a login wall would also make it easier for us to link to the relevant documentation (in addition to quoting it) and thus possibly increasing the page rank of your own site as well.
4. Use github to disseminate your code samples and tutorials (and no, I have no affiliation with github in case you were wondering). It wouldn't hurt to turn on its builtin issue tracker and its builtin wiki for documentation as well. The StackOverflow format can only get you so far by itself. While I'm at it, please give us access to your main bug tracker as well, if you're not already giving it to us.
5. Clarify who qualifies for the raffle/contest. Which countries? Age limit(s)? Former employees? Domestic partners or family members of employees? Employees of a company the company running the contest partially owns? Etc. Have non-monetary awards for users that can't officially enter your contest. Just give us a way to identify those competing, and those not officially competing, so that we know who they are also.
6. Create different categories and different ways prizes will be judged, or raffled away. This way, if the raffle goes horribly wrong, or gets gamed in some way, there is an alternative way of participating in the contest.
7. Do not make your prizes too big. It's better to have many smaller prizes instead of having too few larger prizes.
8. Give yourself an out if something goes wrong. Realize that some people have access to thousands of loyal facebook friends, or thousands of twitter followers, most of which are not developers, nor part of your target demographics, but that could potentially come to this site and register just to upvote low quality answers of a personal friend.
9. Keep one or several awards not connected to the raffle, but given out according to your own judgment after you know the results of the raffle. This way, if you know someone who did some outstanding work, or stands out in some other way, but wasn't lucky enough to win the raffle, you can give that person your own award.
10. Note that some users are ego driven, so giving out titles, or marking them as official winners of a contest/category, will be enough of an incentive, but that incentive goes away if a raffle is involved in getting them that title. Again, that's why I don't think a company should put all their eggs in the raffle basket.
11. Note that some users get turned off by monetary awards, or even ego-driven awards, and they do not want to give the impression that they're answering questions for the awards. The same goes for users that work for a company that would frown upon them if they found out, they answered questions for a contest. Allow those users to answer questions, but to visibly opt-out from the contest on the answer itself, to make sure there is no misunderstanding as to their underlying motivation for answering questions.

Comment: (This may or may not mitigate your point #2.) The Mindtopiary sandbox does require signup, but **signing up for the contest** is not required to get into the sandbox. Two different registrations there.

Comment: Well, they're just wishes at the top of my head. I do not expect all of them to be implemented. But yes, I was thinking about the signup to the sandbox itself.

Answer (score 9):

Questions I have are in bold.

1. **How can we avoid a sudden influx of low quality posts?** Maybe exclude posts that get into the VLQ review queue. This should hopefully ensure posts for the contest are quality posts. A warning that a post doesn't meet quality standards would be nice, but could quickly become very complicated (and lead to further gaming).
2. **How do we ensure there's enough time to moderate the potential influx?** Could we close the contest with some time before prize decisions are made (probably at least 1-2 weeks). This gives the community, mods, and staff time to clean up the tags in question. Count number of entries once the tag is cleaned.
3. **How do we avoid vote manipulation (serial voting, sock puppets)?** Consider making the serial voting script more sensitive for these tags for the duration of the contest. This should help mitigate vote gaming. Maybe we should also apply IP based limits on (new?) accounts being allowed access to the contest.
4. **Will this contest require hardware users may not already have?** If so, can they get it in a timely manner?
5. **What about old questions/answers?** Can/should we reward users who are already active in the tags in questions? Like [bobinice's famous XHTML regex parsing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/264775) - would he be retroactively entered, or would he be SOL?
6. **If we're adding new extrinsic motivation (prizes), should we adjust the one we already get?** Should we somehow adjust the reputation or badge gains for users participating in the contest?
7. **Why a raffle?** Why not select X high-quality questions (and possibly their associated answers) and Y high-quality answers (and maybe their associated questions) to be rewarded in some form. If the contest ignores reputation entirely it might help reduce the risks of vote manipulation.
8. **Are there limits to who can "play" in this contest?** Location? Age? Previous tag participation? Minimum reputation? Maximum number of failed review audits?
9. **How do we limit pain/damage to users that choose not (or are not allowed) to join in with the contest?** Do we give them more reputation? A badge? Do we clearly mark "this guy isn't in the contest, please don't use your sock puppets on him"?
10. **How will the tags in question be displayed in the review queue?** Will they be unchanged? Will they only be shown to non-participants?
11. **What impact will edits have?** Do I get entries for editing? If I edit a good question/answer to make it bad, do I get penalized? Do the original posters get a chance to fix their question/answer?
12. **What happens if the tag on a question is altered after the fact (added or removed)?** Do we treat it like the gold badge dupe hammer, where original tags are the only thing that matter?
13. **What about tag synonyms or related tags?** For example, say we apply this to [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). Do we count [uitableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcell) if [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) is missing from the question? What about other related tags?
14. **Will gold badge dupe hammer powers apply?**
15. **Will all close reasons count for cancellation?** Is a duplicate something that should be allowed for participation? We generally do seem to consider some valuable (even if only as signposts).

Answer (score 4):

What do the lawyers say?

Your proposal appears to be a contest in which case local laws may apply. For example, in California,

> RULES FOR OPERATION OF CONTESTS AND SWEEPSTAKES
>
> January 2013
>
> [RULES FOR OPERATION OF CONTESTS](http://www.dca.ca.gov/publications/legal_guides/u-3.shtml)
>
> (Business and Professions Code sections 17539-17539.55)
>
> A "contest" is any game, puzzle, scheme, or plan which offers
>   prospective participants the opportunity to receive or compete for
>   gifts or prizes on the basis of skill or skill and chance, and which
>   is conditioned wholly or partly on the payment of some value.

In Great Britain, it may be a competition. For example,

> [Running a competition](http://www.out-law.com/page-6780)
>
> Many organisations seek to attract customers by running competitions
>   for prizes. However, there are regulatory controls on some of these
>   competitions.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the mentioned issue of fraudulent voting by participants, there is also a risk that users who don't like this advertising gimmick will follow the tags and dish out extra downvotes, close votes, flags, harassing comments, etc.

Comment: Re: Close votes, flags, harassing comments, for those three I do have faith in the existing system to take care of this (well-formed questions would not be closed, undeserved flags would not be acted on, harassing comments would be flagged and removed - as is currently the case [and when that system fails the issues are generally resolved well on meta]). For down votes I guess you'd just have to monitor for particular users who cast many down votes in this particular tag. Personally, I appreciate this type of advertising far more than an irrelevant sidebar ad being thrown at me.

Answer (score 2):

If we take into account the *[intrinsic motivation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277164/510711)* mentioned by @RobertCartaino I would not think about anything that needs moderator or SE Staff to keep the contest on road.

How about anyone who does the following qualifies for the raffle:

- register for the raffle
- follow those tags
- visit SO for at least *n* days of the contest

That would remove any motivation for potential harmful behavior but increase the visibility a lot. Both for the company and for SO.

If the company monitors the tag closely and show their support on unclear questions, all those following SO users see that and might gain a positive mindset towards that company and their product.